# Do we not have that $X_1, \ldots, X_n \sim F$ iff $X_1, \ldots, X_n \sim f$?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, independence, density-function

From pg. 39 of *All of Statistics*:

> If $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are independent and each has the same marginal distribution CDF $F$, we say that $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are IID (independent and identically distributed) and we write
>
> $$
> X_1, \ldots, X_n \sim F
> $$
>
> If $F$ has density $f$ we also write $X_1, \ldots X_n \sim f$.

**Question 1:** Why is the primary focus here on $F$ (the CDF) and not $f$ (the density function)?

**Question 2:** Is it not already the case that $X_1, \ldots, X_n \sim F$ iff $X_1, \ldots, X_n \sim f$? That is, is it even possible that a collection of random variables $X_i$ could have the same CDFs $F$ but NOT have the same probability density functions $f$ (in either the discrete or the continuous cases)?

Comment: Many random variables do not have a density function.  Also, even in the continuous distribution case, the cdf does not determine the density (though  admittedly it almost determines the density).

Comment: Let me introduce you to my good friend, [Cantor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution).

Comment: Andre: I made a comment on Robert's post asking if assuming absolute continuity changed things. An $X$ with Cantor distribution as CDF fails to be absolutely continuous, so there might be hope yet!

Answer (score 2):

This is somewhat unfortunate notation, using the same ~ for the CDF and the density.

Every random variable has a CDF, but not every random variable has a probability density function.  In particular, a discrete random variable has a probability mass function rather than a density.  There are also singular continuous distributions, and mixtures of the different types.

Comment: Assuming $X$ is absolutely continuous, do we (at least) then have that $X_1, \ldots, X_n \sim F$ iff $X_1, \ldots, X_n \sim f$?

Comment: The density, for an absolutely continuous $X$, is uniquely determined up to values on sets of measure $0$; changing values of the density on sets of measure $0$ does not affect the distribution.